# Flask-WTForms - FileField() customize button and input

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to customize the button of the FileField() from Flask-WTForms,

This is what I have:

[image]

And I would like at least to change the labels from the button and from the input,

This is the jinja code for the HTML template:

```
<p class = "labels-container-1">
    {{ form.<file_field_object>.label(class_='labels') }} 
    <br> 
    {{ form.<file_field_object>(class_='form-control-files') }}
    {% for err in form.<file_field_object>.errors %}
        <span class= 'error'>{{ err }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</p>
```

And below the FileField() object:

```
avis_imposition = FileField("Avis d'imposition")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution, but you need to change the style to your taste. Wrap the file field in a parent div, give it opacity zero to hide it, and then style the parent div: here is an example

```
<div style="background-color: grey;">
    <span style="position: absolute; color: white">Select Image</span>
    <div style="opacity: 0;">
        {{form.<file_field_object>(id="imgField", **{'onchange':'showImage()'})}}
    </div>
</div>
<img id="target" width="100"/>  <--- this is to preview the image
```

Now write a small script at the end of your html file to load and show the image. again you have to fix the style.

```
function showImage() {
    var imgField = document.getElementById("imgField");
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    var fr=new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function (e) {
        target.src = this.result; 
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(imgField.files[0]);
}
```

Comment: I tried to make a div with an input and a button inside and assign an ID to that group. But apparently it seems to only work with single components. So, I am able to change the jinja code and have either the input or the button, but I can't have both.

Comment: do not add a button, format your parent div to look like one if you want. if you're using bootstrap. do this to the parent div: <div class="btn-primary rounded" style="width: 100; height: 35;">
            <span class="p-1 px-4" style="position: absolute; color: white;">Image</span>

Answer (score 1):

You can edit and style the button in the FileField() Flask-WTForms the following way:

```
{{ form.file_field_object(class='form-control-files', style="display: none") }}
<label class="btn btn-outline-info" for="{{ form.file_field_object.id }}">Browse :-) ...</label>
```

This adds also a different style to the button